# Отобразить картинку средствами php

Tags: curl, php, изображения

Вобщем тяну с помощью curl картинку(allow_url_open для моих целей не подходит).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); - установлен.
```

Если записывать в файл, то всё успешно.

**Попытка№1** Попытка просто $echo картинку:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $img;
```

Безуспешна. ff говорит, что не может отобразить картинку, кидая ошибку "the image путь_до_php_скрипта cannot be displayed because it contains error"

**Попытка№2** Следующая попытка использовать gd:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatefromstring($img);
imagepng($im);
```

Так же проваливаются.

**Поптыка№3** Попытка использовать [DataURI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) следующим образом:

```
$im = base64_encode($img)
#где-то в html
<img src="data: image/png;base64, <?echo $im;?>">
```

На удивление работает(когда я потерял надежду и писал этот вопрос она не работала О_о)

ЧЯДНТ?

==**Решение:**
Мне помог [ob_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-clean.php) прямо перед выводом **Попытка№1-2** заработали.

Comment: Разве я работаю с ними, как с текстовыми? :(
Очень не хочется создавать файл: картинка всегда будет разная. Идеально php должен был отдавать картинку, а в html img src="boo.php"

Comment: @moron попробуйте буфер поочищать, как делают в документации.

> Разве я работаю с ними, как с текстовыми? :(

echo, createimagefrom**string**

Comment: А в доках createimagefromstring разве не бинарный файл представленный как строка получает? http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php

Comment: мой факап.

Comment: В итоге очищение мне помогло. Для будущих поколений главный пост изменил.

Answer (score 1):

> ЧЯДНТ?

работаете с бинарными файлами как с текстовыми (хотя echo, по-моему, должен нормально все вывести)

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
readfile($path);
```

[документация readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php), там они еще принудительно очищают буфер, возможно, это необходимо. Также есть аналогичная функция `fpassthru()`.